# How to make an app communicate with with another one in real time?

Tags: java, android, real-time, communication

I am college student, developing an android app on multiplayer game like online chess and ludo. I know it is broad question, but any help regarding code will be appreciated.

Basically I want to know how to make app communicate with each other (minimum 3 android app). I searched over internet but didn't get any code snippet regarding this. In other words, app should send information about its player's response and position, and it should be displayed on other 2 players in real time.
Please also send me with code for server and help regarding it.
Any architecture of communication over internet will be helpful.

IDE - Android studio (java)

Comment: Can you please share anything you have done so far? Ideally you should not be asking an open question of this sort without showing at the very least some initial attempt.

Comment: May be `WebSocket` will be helpful in your case. There is many tutorials and article available on internet that help you to learn to use WebSockets on Android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Firebase Firestore, it will keep your data in sync across client apps through realtime listeners
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using socket.io library.

please check below example :
https://medium.com/@projectyang/simple-multiplayer-game-with-socket-io-tutorial-part-one-setup-and-movement-ee202024f0ef

My chatting example :
https://github.com/NerdFaisal404/Socket.IO